# Cleaning URL Queries in PHP Causing 500 Internal Server Error

Tags: php, url

I'm working on implementing a RETS server for a client which along with it comes the mountains of forms and input fields. In light of this, in order to keep search queries manageable and to prevent URLs from becoming too long, I wrote a block to clean out the empties and to redirect to a cleaned URL which has no empty GET variables.

I'm imagining that the 500 Internal Server Error is because it's redirecting infinitely. Conversely, testing the cleaned URL does not result in a 500 Internal Server Error.

While working on this locally the problem was non existent for either type of URL. My development environment (WAMP) would correctly redirect and clean URLs without issue. However, integration on a live server now causes this 500 issue.

**PHP:**

```
// Remove Empty Query Parameters
$uri = parse_url($_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']);
if(isset($uri['query'])) {
  parse_str($uri['query'], $uri_query);
  $clean = true;
  foreach($uri_query as $key => $val) {
    if(empty($val)) {
      unset($uri_query[$key]);
      $clean = false;
      // echo '<!-- Removed Empty: '.$key.' -->'."\n";
    }
  }
  $uri_rebuilt = $uri['path'].'?'.http_build_query($uri_query);
  // echo '<!-- '.$clean.' -->'."\n";
  if($clean == false) {
    // echo '<!-- Dirty URL: '.$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'].' -->'."\n";
    // echo '<!-- Clean URL: '.$uri_rebuilt.' -->'."\n";
    header("Location: ".$uri_rebuilt);
    exit;
  } else {
    // echo '<!-- Clean URL! -->';
  }
}
```

With the header/exit commented out, and the echos uncommented, the page reveals that everything is operating as intended. So the problem exists somewhere in the logic of the redirect, or on the server configuration disparity between local and live. If it's the later, what information would I need to provide to the community in order to begin to work it out?

**Output:**

```
<!-- Removed Empty: StreetNumber -->
<!-- Removed Empty: StreetName -->
<!-- Removed Empty: Subdivision -->
<!-- Removed Empty: SchoolElementary -->
<!-- Removed Empty: City -->
<!-- Removed Empty: SchoolJrHigh -->
<!-- Removed Empty: ZipCode -->
<!-- Removed Empty: SchoolSrHigh -->
<!-- Removed Empty: SqftMin -->
<!-- Removed Empty: SqftMax -->
<!-- Removed Empty: StoriesMin -->
<!-- Removed Empty: StoriesMax -->
<!-- Removed Empty: BedsMin -->
<!-- Removed Empty: BedsMax -->
<!-- Removed Empty: BathsMin -->
<!-- Removed Empty: BathsMax -->
<!-- Removed Empty: AcresMin -->
<!-- Removed Empty: AcresMax -->
<!-- Removed Empty: ParkingMin -->
<!-- Removed Empty: ParkingMax -->
<!--  -->
<!-- Dirty URL: /search?display=SearchResults&StateCounty=TN%2BDAVIDSON&PropertyClass=RES&StreetNumber=&StreetName=&Subdivision=&SchoolElementary=&City=&SchoolJrHigh=&ZipCode=&SchoolSrHigh=&PriceMin=100000&PriceMax=110000&SqftMin=&SqftMax=&StoriesMin=&StoriesMax=&BedsMin=&BedsMax=&BathsMin=&BathsMax=&AcresMin=&AcresMax=&ParkingMin=&ParkingMax= -->
<!-- Clean URL: /search?display=SearchResults&StateCounty=TN%2BDAVIDSON&PropertyClass=RES&PriceMin=100000&PriceMax=110000 -->
```

Comment: Do you have access to the httpd logs on the live system? For a 500 it should be reporting something.

Comment: Unfortunately I do not.

Comment: Are you able to make a copy of the page at a different URL on live (something not public) and add the debugging information you've used on dev? the echo statements and comment the header.